# CSRF vulnerability in Oracle ADF web application

Tags: web-application, csrf, oracle

I am pentesting Oracle ADF web application. One of the requests to delete some content consists of parameters like `_adf.ctrl-state` and `javax.faces.ViewState`, which seem to be random numbers, active only during one session.

I'm not sure if this prevents form CSRF attacks? I found some resources like for example [this](https://dzone.com/articles/preventing-csrf-jsf-20), which suggest adding aditional anti-CSRF token.

Comment: The viewstate might contain some kind of CSRF protection (see [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8744/does-asp-net-viewstate-implicitly-prevent-csrf-attacks-what-does-this-mean-for) for a similar discussion for ASP.NET).

Comment: Can't really say more than that without more information. I'd say your best bet is just to try and see if it works.

Comment: I've seen similar things which I felt were CSRF tokens but were instead a weird request and session identifier for bug/issue resolution. Usually devs who know what they're doing and why they're doing it call it what it is: a `csrf_token`